# Google Glass GDK: Progress Indicator?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Using the GDK (or in some other way), is there a way to display a progress indicator similar to the one displayed when connecting to a WiFi network on Glass? (the "spinning" lines on the bottom of the display, kind of like at the end of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3ncmeGaKN0)

Thanks!

Comment: Excellent question. I was looking for the same thing. I added a standard horizontal progress bar in my project, and it works fine, but I'd like to match the style with the Glass style I'm seeing in the rest of the UI. Wondering if this is just a parm in the layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is resolved by google with **Slider** (global UX Components) https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/slider

Answer (score 25):

**`UPD 04.11.2014:`** Google released [`Slider`](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/slider) -- UX component suitable for this. You should better use it instead of the extracted project.

---

I've extracted Google Glass Progress Bar from GlassHome.apk and created a library project based on that: https://github.com/pif/glass-progress-bar

- supports indeterminate
- supports default progress

Usage is described in README in the [repository](https://github.com/pif/glass-progress-bar).

And yes, everyone is still waiting for a full-featured set of Glass Views.

[image: Here's a demo of what was achieved]

**Update**: I extracted MessageDialog as well. You can find it in the same library.

[image: Here's a demo of MessageDialog]

Comment: Awesome! Just what I need right now. I will add it to Glasquare (4sq for Glass)

Comment: Send pull requests, if you have any issues integrating it! PS. Glasquare is nice!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! For my case I needed to be notified when the animation finished so I forked your repo and created a listener for it. https://github.com/Viddi/Glass-SliderView Thanks again!

Comment: Sweet! Can you think of any way to do this directly on a Live Card Remote View?

Comment: @swooby I'm not sure, if you can do it using RemoteViews. Probably, you can try using that on LiveCard via frequent updates.

Answer (score 3):

This comes pretty close, but the color is off (blue/teal/whatever instead of white).

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
```

Sample (via [OkGlassFindACat](https://github.com/patridge/OkGlassFindACat/)):

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/someProgressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
```

[image: Glass progress bar using progressBarStyleHorizontal]

I definitely haven't figured out how to override that color, though.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late but here's my version :)

https://github.com/prt2121/glass-gdk-progressbar

**adding to your project in the gradle file**

```
compile 'com.github.prt2121:ProgressBar:1.0@aar'
```

screenshot:

[image: white]

**changing color**

```
app:progress_color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The GDK overrides themes for some widgets automatically to provide a proper Glass-like appearance, such as `TextView`. For widgets that don't yet have that theming, please [file an issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) here so that we can track it.

Answer (score 1):

I put together the answer above to create a general layout for my card-list loader activities.  Here's the layout file `card_scroll_with_progress_layout.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView
        android:id="@+id/card_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Then in the onCreate I get the progress bar and set it rolling:

```
View rootLayout = getLayoutInflater()
                      .inflate(R.layout.card_scroll_with_progress_layout, null);
mProgressBar = (ProgressBar)rootLayout.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mCardScrollView = (CardScrollView)rootLayout
                      .findViewById(R.id.card_scroll_view);
mCardScrollView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
setContentView(rootLayout);
```

Later on in my loader callback I hide the progress bar and activate the card scroll view:

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    if (loader.getId() == mLoaderId) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mCardScrollView.activate();
    }
}
```

This seems to be working well as a paradigm for handling various json loading into a list of cards in the GDK.

Answer (score 0):

We have been having a similar issue and found a hybrid approach that works for us. We use the standard progress bar @patridge mentioned in a previous post and applied generated Holo styles provided by [Android Holo Colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/).

We were able to generate a white progress bar images, animation, layer and style that looks very similar to the built in GDK version. You can increase the height of the bar to match the GDK by editing the size of Holo Color's generated png images.

You will need the generated files included in your project, but here is what our theme looks like afterwards:

```
<style name="OurGlassTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/ProgressBarGlass</item>
</style>
<style name="ProgressBarGlass" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/glass_progress_horizontal_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/glass_progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">16dip</item>
</style>
```

I know it's super tedious, but it gets us there while @giladgo 's accepted submission to the Glass developers to provide a GDK Progress Bar is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [ProgressBar](https://gitorious.org/zoom-in/zoom-in/source/3473d0881d3730636f0ecf8fd6bd311302a4c3c5:src/com/google/glass/glassware/zoomin/ProgressBar.java) from `zoom-in` project.