# How do i display a progress bar for CardScrollView in Google Glass?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

So I've got my little beginning of an app loading data from json into a CardScrollView.  Sometimes this takes a few seconds, so I need a loading screen.  Normally I'd do this with the progress action bar or a progress bar spinning around.  I found a question around this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237873/google-glass-gdk-progress-indicator

So far so good, however I can't determine how to construct a layout for my activity so I see the progress loading and then when data load is finished, the card scroll view.  What I'm doing now is first I set the loading view in the onCreate:

```
setContentView(mLoadingView)
```

Then later once the loader is finished I call:

```
mCardScrollView.activate()
setContentView(mCardScrollView)
```

Not only does this feel hackish, but it doesn't handle the case of reloading data.  Normally I'd do this in android with a frame layout xml which would have the progress bar and list view in it and then toggle progress bar visibility / progress.  But I'm not sure how to do this in glass.  Maybe I'm not even following the right "glass paradigm".  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Currently in the GDK sneak peek, you'll have to roll your own solution like you've already done. But you can track the feature request for a Glass-style progress here [here on our issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=271).